# Set variable to run all special calsses in c++

Tags: c++

This is my program. I want to set a `extern` variable to detect each class like this:

```
template <typename Each_Class_Type>
void SET(Each_Class_Type GET, int Id)
{
    extern map<int, Each_Class_Type> Load_Each_Class;

    Load_Each_Class[Id] = GET;
}

class First_C
{
public:

    int Load_Id = 1;
    string name = "This is Class 1.";
};

class Second_C
{
public:

    int Load_Id = 2;
    string name = "This is Class 2.";
};

class Third_C
{
public:

    int Load_Id = 3;
    string name = "This is Class 3.";
};

int main()
{
    First_C  This_Class;
    Second_C This_Class2;
    Third_C  This_Class3;

    SET(This_Class, This_Class.Load_Id);
    SET(This_Class2, This_Class2.Load_Id);
    SET(This_Class3, This_Class3.Load_Id);

    // Now i want each class joined to  (Load_Each_Class) variable and ...
    cout << Load_Each_Class[1].name << "\n";
    cout << Load_Each_Class[2].name << "\n";
    cout << Load_Each_Class[3].name << "\n";
}
```

Now I want this program print this:

```
This is Class 1.
This is Class 2.
This is Class 3.
```

...but it seems there is problem in my program. there are so many error on this program ... the second type of Load_Each_Class is the type of class 1 and i want to use it for calss 2 and class 3 and it seams there is some problem

Comment: Please format your question. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: you want `static` and not `extern`

Comment: What is the problem with your program?

Comment: You should start with a simpler exercise. And do something about your spelling, grammar and punctuation.

Comment: Sorry, but i dont need your suggestion the only thing i need is the answer of this question ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem with you program is that your design is wrong. You are clearly expecting `Load_Each_Class` to be a single registry of all 'loaded classes' which maps an id to an instance of the loaded class. But your definition of `Load_Each_Class` tries to include the type of the loaded class. Each variable in C++ only has a single type. It's not possible to have a map whose `value_type` varies depending on the value of the key. Essentially you are confusing run time information, what has been loaded, with compile time information, what classes exist.

You need to redesign your code. Since it's not clear exactly what you are trying to achieve it's hard to give advice on that. You might be able to do something with inheritance, have all your classes derived from a common parent. Or you might be able to do something with `typeid` if you really what to store static information about each type.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there are several problems in this.

First, `extern` is the incorrect keyword for what you are attempting to do. `static` is the keyword to make a variable common to all calls of a function, and all instances of a class (should it prefix a class variable).

Second, every call to `SET` effectively creates a separate `Load_Each_Class` for every `Each_Class_Type` you pass it. None of these maps are within the scope of `main()`, ergo calling them within that function is illegal.

Third, you cannot set the value of class members the way you are. You must define them within functions or within a constructor (see below).

Frankly, there is far too much wrong with what you have posted to simply fix it. The whole method is incorrect. You should be utilizing polymorphism, not templates, to accomplish the task of storing multiple classes of different types in the same container. As such, here is a suggested alternative approach:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"
#include "map"

using namespace std;

class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass( int Load_Id, string name ) : Load_Id( Load_Id ), name( name ) {};

    const int Load_Id;
    const string name;
};

class First_C : public BaseClass
{
public:
    First_C( ) : BaseClass( 1, "This is Class 1." ) {};
};

class Second_C : public BaseClass
{
public:
    Second_C( ) : BaseClass( 2, "This is Class 2." ) {};
};

class Third_C : public BaseClass
{
public:
    Third_C( ) : BaseClass( 3, "This is Class 3." ) {};
};

int main()
{
    map<int, BaseClass*> classes;

    First_C  This_Class;
    Second_C This_Class2;
    Third_C  This_Class3;

    classes[This_Class.Load_Id] = &This_Class;
    classes[This_Class2.Load_Id] = &This_Class2;
    classes[This_Class3.Load_Id] = &This_Class3;

    cout << classes[1]->name << "\n";
    cout << classes[2]->name << "\n";
    cout << classes[3]->name << "\n";
}
```

This has the intended output:

```
/a.exe
This is Class 1.
This is Class 2.
This is Class 3.
```

The common base class `BaseClass` could be avoided by using a `void*`, but that would require extra (potentially and probably unsafe) casting. Additionally, you should be cautious with public member variables, which is why I have declared them as `const` - they cannot be modified once the object is created.